# How to stop form submit from going into a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the current situation, and the code is self explanatory.

Form Html

```
<form id="register" action="example.com/signup" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
    <label for="email">Email</label><br />

    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label>

    <button type="submit" name="register" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('#register').submit(function(event){

event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault(); 

alert('fff');

if(condition)
{
    $(this).submit();
}
else
{
    //dostuff
    if(condition)
    {
        //dostuff
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).submit();
    }
}

});
```

But the form submit goes into the loop, how do I prevent it from happening ?

Comment: If the form goes into an infinite loop, your problem is your condition, can you give us your condition ? :)

Comment: May be I am wrong but if you invoke $(this).submit() inside submit(), it is a recursion.

Comment: @user1551066 Yes, I understand that, I need to submit the form from that JavaScript function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bit of code that you currently have will initiate your submit callback again

```
$(this).submit();
```

You don't want that - you just want to `return true;` if you want to proceed with the submission or `return false;` if you don't.

---

Also, you **don't** need this part

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: But then how do I submit the form from JavaScript/JQuery ? Since In one of those conditions(it's a stripped done code presented here), I am appending custom values to hidden fields, and those values must be submitted to the PHP script handling the submission.

Comment: Clicking the submit "initiates" the form submit. Now, since you have callbacks, these get executed first (before the submit is sent to the server) and you could cancel the submit in these callbacks or you could change any data in the form. 

If you return true, the submit actually goes to the server (you can do anything you want before you return including appending custom values...). If you return false, or cancel the event the submit is cancelled (i.e does not go to the server)